# indices = 2 is not in [0, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm working on a seq2sql project and I successfully build a model but when training I get an error. I'm not using any Keras embedding layer.

```python
M=13 #Question Length
d=40 #Dimention of the LSTM
C=12 #number of table Columns 

batch_size=9
inputs1=Input(shape=(M,100),name='question_token')
Hq=Bidirectional(LSTM(d,return_sequences=True),name='QuestionENC')(inputs1) #this is HQ shape is (num_samples,13,80)

inputs2=Input(shape=(C,3,100),name='col_token')
col_lstm_layer=Bidirectional(LSTM(d,return_sequences=False),name='ColENC')

def hidd(te):
    t=tf.Variable(initial_value=1,dtype=tf.int32)

    for i in range(batch_size):  
        t=tf.assign(t,i)
        Z = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(te, t)
        print(col_lstm_layer(Z))
        h=tf.reshape(col_lstm_layer(Z),[1,C,d*2])
        if i==0:
#             cols_last_hidden=tf.Variable(initial_value=h)
            cols_last_hidden=tf.stack(h)#this is because it gives an error if we use tf.Variable here
        else:
            cols_last_hidden=tf.concat([cols_last_hidden,h],0)#shape of this one is (num_samples,num_col,80) 80 is last encoding of each column
    return cols_last_hidden

cols_last_hidden=Lambda(hidd)(inputs2)

Hq=Dense(d*2,name='QuestionLastEncode')(Hq)

I=tf.Variable(initial_value=1,dtype=tf.int32)
J=tf.Variable(initial_value=1,dtype=tf.int32)

K=1

def get_col_att(tensors):
    global K,all_col_attention
    if K:
        t=tf.Variable(initial_value=1,dtype=tf.int32)

        for i in range(batch_size):
            t=tf.assign(t,i)
            x = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tensors[0], t)
    #         print("tensors[1]:",tensors[1])
            y = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tensors[1], t)
    #         print("x shape",x.shape,"y shape",y.shape)
            y=tf.transpose(y)
#             print("x shape",x.shape,"y",y.shape)
            Ecol=tf.reshape(tf.transpose(tf.tensordot(x,y,axes=1)),[1,C,M])

            if i==0: 
#                 all_col_attention=tf.Variable(initial_value=Ecol,name=""+i)
                all_col_attention=tf.stack(Ecol)
            else:
                all_col_attention=tf.concat([all_col_attention,Ecol],0)

    K=0
    print("all_col_attention",all_col_attention)
    return all_col_attention

total_alpha_sel_lambda=Lambda(get_col_att,name="Alpha")([Hq,cols_last_hidden])   
total_alpha_sel=Dense(13,activation="softmax")(total_alpha_sel_lambda)
# print("Hq",Hq," total_alpha_sel_lambda shape",total_alpha_sel_lambda," total_alpha_sel shape",total_alpha_sel.shape)
def get_EQcol(tensors): 
    global K
    if K:
        t=tf.Variable(initial_value=1,dtype=tf.int32)
        global all_Eqcol

        for i in range(batch_size):
            t=tf.assign(t,i)
            x = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tensors[0], t)
            y = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tensors[1], t)
            Eqcol=tf.reshape(tf.tensordot(x,y,axes=1),[1,C,d*2])

            if i==0:
#                 all_Eqcol=tf.Variable(initial_value=Eqcol,name=""+i)
                all_Eqcol=tf.stack(Eqcol)
            else:
                all_Eqcol=tf.concat([all_Eqcol,Eqcol],0)

    K=0
    print("all_Eqcol",all_Eqcol)
    return all_Eqcol
K=1
EQcol=Lambda(get_EQcol,name='EQcol')([total_alpha_sel,Hq])#total_alpha_sel(12x13) Hq(13xd*2)
EQcol=Dropout(.2)(EQcol)

L1=Dense(d*2,name='L1')(cols_last_hidden)
L2=Dense(d*2,name='L2')(EQcol)
L1_plus_L2=Add()([L1,L2])
pre=Flatten()(L1_plus_L2)
Psel=Dense(12,activation="softmax")(pre)

model=Model(inputs=[inputs1,inputs2],outputs=Psel)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

earlyStopping=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=7, verbose=0, mode='auto')

history=model.fit([Equestion,Col_Embeddings],y_train,epochs=50,validation_split=.1,shuffle=False,callbacks=[earlyStopping],batch_size=batch_size)
```

The shapes of the Equestion, Col_Embeddings, and y_train are (10, 12, 3, 100) ,(10, 13, 100) and (10, 12).

I searched about this error but in all cases they have used an embedding layer incorrectly. Here I get this error even though I'm not using one.

```
indices = 2 is not in [0, 1)
[[{{node lambda_3/embedding_lookup_2}} = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@col_token_2"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_col_token_2_0_1, lambda_3/Assign_2, lambda_3/embedding_lookup_2/axis)]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here was the batch size is defined at the graph level.here i have used `batch_size =9` for the graph and yes i get batch size of `9` for training by the validation split `.1` for the full batch size of `10` but for the validation i left only one sample because `10*.1` is one.

So the batch size of `1` cannot be passed to the graph because it needs batch size of `9`.that's why this error comes

As for the solution i put the `batch_size=1` and then it works fine also got a good accuracy by using `batch_size=1`.

Hope this will help someone.

Cheers ..

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was due to bad form of my input data. You have to double check your input data to the model and it depends on your model input.