# What if the sample size is not divisible by batch_size in Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

What if we specify batch size as 15 and the sample size of 1000 which is not divisible by 15 in Keras model training?.should it still able to train?

also I have looked in to this answer but it's not helping [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974340/keras-what-if-the-size-of-data-is-not-divisible-by-batch-size)

please can anybody explain this Thank you.

Comment: Did you try? It works.

Comment: yeh i tried in previous models that i have created its working but in the latest model that i have created gives an error.but if give divisible number then it works fine.

Comment: If you have errors then you should include it in your question, along with the code that produced it and any tracebacks.

Comment: yes Matias here is the code but it somewhat lengthy,i have posted it as another question yesterday but i did'nt get any answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54141106/indices-2-is-not-in-0-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer for this. If this is the case, it will take the remaining 10 samples to the last step of the epoch.

Eg: `15x66+10=1000` that means it will take 66 batches of size 15 and for the final steps it takes only 10.

Anyways this will only work with `input_shape`, if we use `batch_input_shape` it will give us an error because we are specifying the batch shape in the graph level.

Answer (score 5):

This is no problem for your training and validation data. The generator will take care of this. Hence you can simply use:

```
STEPS = train_generator.n // train_generator.batch_size
VALID_STEPS = validation_generator.n // train_generator.batch_size

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=VALID_STEPS)
```

However, for your testset make sure that the batch size fits the data, otherwise you run a risk of your predictions not matching your true labels when comparing both (please check this article which highlights this https://medium.com/difference-engine-ai/keras-a-thing-you-should-know-about-keras-if-you-plan-to-train-a-deep-learning-model-on-a-large-fdd63ce66bd2). You can ensure that the batch size fits your data by using a loop for example:

```
for i in range(1,160):
    if len(test_data) % i == 0:
        div = i
batch_size = div
```

Comment: Thanks. I was making logic to create 0 padded samples to make remainders from division into a full batch. This is going to help from wasting a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

in tf1.14 you should not care about this issue.
It seems that in tf1.15, you need to worry about this.